# How to load event in to table calendar from sqflite database in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am going to create a flutter event app using table calendar and sqflite.my My problem is how can I show table calendar event from saved event in database.? This is my table:

```
await db.execute('''
      CREATE TABLE leave_Calender_Details(
          "leave_catergoty" TEXT,
          "leave_start_date" DATETIME,
          "leave_end_date" DATETIME,
          "reason" TEXT
      )
      ''');
```

Here is my my helper class:

```
Future<List<LeaveCalenderLeaveDetails>> getCalenderLeaveDetails() async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    var _leave = await db.rawQuery('SELECT leave_catergoty,leave_start_date, leave_end_date,reason,reason FROM leave_Calender_Details');
    List<LeaveCalenderLeaveDetails> _leaveList =
        _leave.isNotEmpty ? _leave.map((c) => LeaveCalenderLeaveDetails.fromMap(c)).toList() : [];
   print(_leave);
    return _leaveList;
  }
```

Here is my model class:

```
class LeaveCalenderLeaveDetails {
  String leave_catergoty;
  DateTime leave_start_date;
  String leave_end_date;
  String reason;

  LeaveCalenderLeaveDetails({
    required this.leave_catergoty,
    required this.leave_start_date,
    required this.leave_end_date,
    required this.reason,
  });

  factory LeaveCalenderLeaveDetails.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      LeaveCalenderLeaveDetails(
        leave_catergoty: json['leave_catergoty'],
        leave_start_date: json['leave_start_date'],
        leave_end_date: json['leave_end_date'],
        reason: json['reason'],
      );
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'leave_catergoty': leave_catergoty,
      'leave_start_date': leave_start_date,
      'leave_end_date': leave_end_date,
      'reason': reason,
    };
  }
}
```

How can I show events in database from table calendar? This is a way i have tried. Please help me. I am a new for flutter.

```
class MyHomePage extends State<LeaveCalender> {
  late DateTime _focusedDay;
  late DateTime _selectedDay;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _focusedDay = DateTime.now();
    _selectedDay = DateTime.now();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Calender View'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<LeaveCalenderLeaveDetails>>(
        future: DatabaseHelper.instance.getCalenderLeaveDetails(),
        builder: (BuildContext context,
            AsyncSnapshot<List<LeaveCalenderLeaveDetails>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<LeaveCalenderLeaveDetails>? allEvents = snapshot.data;
            if (allEvents!.isNotEmpty) {}
          }
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TableCalendar(
                  calendarStyle: const CalendarStyle(
                    weekendTextStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
                  focusedDay: _focusedDay,
                  firstDay: DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 1000)),
                  lastDay: DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 1000)),
                  selectedDayPredicate: (day) => isSameDay(day, _selectedDay),
                  onDaySelected: (selectedDay, focusedDay) {
                    setState(() {
                      _selectedDay = selectedDay;
                      _focusedDay = focusedDay;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```